# DB table design for duration of event

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, business-intelligence

I'm writing a program that will track the duration time of tasks. Some tasks might be paused while other tasks are being performed and that time should not count. I have two ideas for the design and I need a push to the right direction, or maybe a better approach.

I want to keep in mind some future reports such as average duration time for tasks of the same type, adding duration times for events that occurred the same day or month, etc.

First.

One row for each event. Start Time and End Time are 2 columns in the table. The end time remains blank until the End Time is recorded. Duration time is then calculated by subtracting start time to the end time.

```
--------------------------------------
|EventId  | Start Time  |  End Time  |
--------------------------------------
|1        | 9:30 am     |  10:00 am  |
--------------------------------------
|2        |10:00 am     |  11:00 am  |
--------------------------------------
```

Second.
Two rows for each event and the type of entry in another column. No fields remain null and the duration time is calculated by joining both entries for the event and subtracting the timestamp for the start entry to the end entry.

```
-----------------------------------------------
|EventId  | Start Time  |  Type      |  GUID  |
-----------------------------------------------
|1        | 9:30 am     |     S      |  XX..X |
-----------------------------------------------
|1        |10:00 am     |     E      |  YY..Y |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to record start and end time, I would go with first option. However, you you think you might need to have a record of more event types in the future (i.e. Pause_start, Pause_end, etc.) then I would go with the second option.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 won't allow you to pause tasks and not count the paused time as part of the total time. If that's a definite requirement, I don't think you can use Option 1. Otherwise, I would prefer Option 1 as it's nice and simple.

If you need to keep track of "events" for each task like Start, Pause, Un-pause and Stop, then I would suggest using two tables. One for Tasks and another for TaskEvents (with a foreign key to the Task.Id). This option will give you more control but it will probably be more work to report on it accurately.